# cannot access my cisco 881W AP interface

Tags: cisco, access-point

I have a new Cisco 881w AP and I am trying to get to the AP interface.

When i follow the procedures outlined by Cisco, i get asked for a username and password. I have tried all the suggested passwords and all have failed authentication. I get a lot of messages like:

```
User Access Verification  Username: Not in Bound state. 
*Dec 19 11:26:46.996: %SM_LICENSE-6-BOOTIMAGE_CHANGE_TO_AUTO: Boot image has been changed to autonomous image Please use router EXEC CLI service-module wlan-ap 0 reload to bootup autonomous image on AP  
*Dec 19 11:26:48.156: %CAPWAP-3-ERRORLOG: Not sending discovery request AP does not have an IP!!
*Dec 19 11:26:48.156: %CAPWAP-3-DHCP_RENEW: Could not discover WLC using DHCP IP. Renewing DHCP IP.
```

The software and IOS versions are:

```
flash:c880data-universalk9-mz.124-20.T4.bin
Cisco IOS Software, C880  Version 12.4(20)T4,
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reset it to factory default settings](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/800-series-routers/qa_c67_458826.html) with the reset button on the device (hold it down as the device boots up) to clear out whatever configuration it has on it, and then login with [the default username and password (`admin` for both](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/800/software/configuration/guide/SCG800Guide/SCG800_Guide_BookMap_chapter_01001.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response . Ultimately i had to reset the AP to factory defaults as you suggested but using the command "service-module wlan-ap0 reset default-config".
What i think happened was the unit was not new as thought .The  AP was never reset to factory default and had  some previous configuration . I actually should have figured it out sooner and not assume the vendor  was being truthful. All is well now.
Thanks